# Rails/Postgresql: Foreign keys stored in an array not returning all associated rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models

```
Product { id, name, tags_id[] }
Tag { id, name }
```

tags_id is an array that stores the ids of Tags.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, foreign_key: 'id'
end
```

Let's say I have a product with two tags(1,2)

When I query for the product, it only loads one tag, the first one.

```
Product.includes(:tags).all
```

Here is how the query looks like:

```
SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" IN (1)
```

Is there an option I need to pass to has_many of Product to receive both the tags? Is this even possible?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try `tag_ids`, not `tags_id` column.
2. As I know it, you can't do that. Just place standard `product_id` column for tags, and remove `tag_ids` column.

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup would not work.

You need to check `has_array_of` gem from [here](https://github.com/marshall-lee/has_array_of).

Comment: The gem is still in development and author is apparently not responding to any one.